# NiceGui: Hide table header

Tags: python, nicegui

Following the [documentation example](https://nicegui.io/documentation/table).

I wasn't able to figure out how to remove the table headers `<th>`, in this case the "Name" and "Age" row.

```
columns = [
    {'name': 'name', 'label': 'Name', 'field': 'name', 'required': True, 'align': 'left'},
    {'name': 'age', 'label': 'Age', 'field': 'age', 'sortable': True},
]
rows = [
    {'name': 'Alice', 'age': 18},
    {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 21},
    {'name': 'Carol'},
]
ui.table(columns=columns, rows=rows, row_key='name')

ui.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "hidden" class to the table header like this:

```py
ui.table(columns=columns, rows=rows, row_key='name').props('table-header-class=hidden')
```

Comment: How / where can I find the list of available props?

Comment: @xvan As mentioned in the [documentation](https://nicegui.io/documentation/table), `ui.table` is based on [Quasar's QTable](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#qtable-api). There you can find a list of all props this component has to offer.